# Having problems clearing an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I m having a 2d arraylist and inside a loop i want to parse every 1d list of the 2d list to a temporary list. Also I want at the end of every iteration i want to clear this temporary list so to the next step to parse the i-est list of my initial 2d.

The code its the following:

```
 List<List<Integer>> conVert = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
 List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for (int i = 0; i<conVert.size(); i++){
    temp.addAll(conVert.get(i));
    Collections.sort(temp);
    System.out.println(temp);

    for(int j = 0; j<temp.size(); j++){
        // several commands
    }
    temp.clear();
 }
```

I have several commands which is not function well due to that temp doesnt clear properly. Any idea? When i put in clear in the beggining i m having problems with conVert,

Comment: I suggest you try running your code in a debugger. I can assure you that List.clear() does work and has been tested/used for many years now. ;) What happens when you create a new `temp` on every iteration? Does the problem go away?

Comment: the problem is that in every iteration this codes add a new list in temp so if the conVert.get(0)=[1,2] then in the first iter temp = [1,2] conVert.get(1)= [3,4] in the second iter temp = [1,2,3,4].

Comment: @zenitis Is the above code not the actual code?

Comment: @zenitis the above code attempt to clear the list after each itereation, this is not what you said in the comment

Comment: What are those several commands? if they don't alter temp, then it's your 2d list that is malformed.

Comment: The code is 400 lines :) is not efficiency possible to post it. But this code is not the problem. I have the same if I remove it and try just to clear temp list after every iteration,

Answer (score 0):

You could use a brand-new `List` instead of clearing the "old" one. Why would you need an empty `List` after the for-loop? There is nothing to be gained by reusing such basic data structures and may even have a reverse effect.

When your `List` runs out of scope, it will be garbage collected at virtually no cost, while explicitly emptying it requires some resources.

**EDIT** : I guess in this case it is better to let the code speak for itself:

```
 List<List<Integer>> conVert = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

 for (int i = 0; i<conVert.size(); i++){
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    temp.addAll(conVert.get(i));
    Collections.sort(temp);
    System.out.println(temp);

    for(int j = 0; j<temp.size(); j++){
        // several commands
    }
}
```

Comment: What i gained is to parse in temp list the second list of conVert(which as already said is a 2darrayList). In the first step i want to parse the first conVert.get(0) int temp list in the second iteration the second list conVert.get(1) e.c.t

Comment: @zenitis I guess, it is better to illustrate my point wiht code (as always :) ) Please try the adapted code in my edit and see if it works for you.